# How to Combine Two PipeWire Audio Sources/Monitors

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, pipewire

So here's my issue. I'm on Linux, and I use the program ReplaySorcery for my Shadowplay program. It works pretty well; no complaints. But one minor issue is that I can only record either desktop audio or mic input. I can't record both. So is there a way to create another audio monitor in PipeWire that is a combination of the two? That way I can set that as my audio device in ReplaySorcery's config. Alternatively, if anyone knows how to set two audio sources as monitors in ReplaySorcery's config, that would work, too.

Comment: You can do it the same way as before with pulseaudio/ALSA by using [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/).

Comment: Thank you, but could you help me with doing that? I went ahead and installed JACK but I have no idea what I'm looking at.

Comment: Alrighty then. Thanks, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for combining multiple sources into one in the Wiki [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices#combine-source-selected-channels-and-sources).

You will want to set all occurences of `audio.position` and `combine.audio.position` to `[ FL FR ]`, so you get the stereo channels mixed together.

The names of your sources (`node.name`) you can find with `pw-cli list-objects Node`. Look for descriptions you recoginze, e.g. from other apps to change sound settings.

The whole file goes into your `~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf.d/` and needs a `.conf` ending.